# Symfony 2.7: Could not load type "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType"

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.7

I am working on an application based on Symfony 2.7. I have a custom form type containing the following code:

```
namespace MyCompany\AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class,
                [
                    'attr'=>
                        [
                            'placeholder' => 'Your name'
                        ],
                    'constraints' =>
                        [
                            new NotBlank(['message' => 'Please provide your name'])
                        ]
                ]
            )
        ;
    }
...
```

... and when I load the form, I get the following InvalidArgumentException:

> Could not load type
>   "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType"

I have verified that the TextType class exists.

I tried using composer dump, and it didn't seem to help. In addition, I tried removing the vendor directory and redoing composer install, and that didn't help either.

What else can I try?

Comment: You can run `composer dump` in order to refresh the vendors cache, or remove the `vendor/` directory like [someone did](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1985#issuecomment-161743797).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, AL. I just tried using `composer dump`, and it didn't seem to help. I also just tried removing the `vendor` directory and redoing `composer install`, and that didn't help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use fully qualified class names to denote form types in Symfony v2.7 - that was added in v2.8. You need to denote your types by passing an instance instead:

```
$builder
    ->add('name', new TextType(),
        [
            'attr'        =>
                [
                    'placeholder' => 'Your name',
                ],
            'constraints' =>
                [
                    new NotBlank(['message' => 'Please provide your name']),
                ],
        ]
    );
```

Or by using the [shorthand name](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types.html#supported-field-types) e.g `text`:

```
$builder
    ->add('name', 'text',
        [
            'attr'        =>
                [
                    'placeholder' => 'Your name',
                ],
            'constraints' =>
                [
                    new NotBlank(['message' => 'Please provide your name']),
                ],
        ]
    );
```

Symfony v2.7 isn't maintained anymore though, so I'd highly recommend upgrading to at least v2.8